# MS Teams App 'Go to website' button function not working

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have developed a Custom Tab in Microsoft Teams and it works perfectly fine. But I am not able to use this functionality in the Teams Mobile App. It also breaks when I try to click on the 'Go to website' button available in the MS Teams App.

After looking into the issue, it was found out that the session data/variables are not getting set. In both these cases, MS Teams app uses browser support and the session data need to be transferred from the MS Teams app to the browser.

Is there a way we can do this from within MS Teams or am I missing something in the development?

Comment: Mobile browser won't receive Microsoft Teams context. Could you please try opening Tabs directly in Teams by clicking on [Open button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMPbI.png) on Tab's menu?

Comment: Thanks @Wajeed-MSFT, I missed that button. But for some reason, the pop-up for authentication does not work. I checked for settings that block pop-ups. Also the pop-up works on other tabs.

Comment: Are you using [Task Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/task-modules/task-modules-overview)? Could you please share some screenshots?

Comment: No @Wajeed-MSFT, I created a custom app that uses MS authentication method. So whenever there is no token available while accessing the tab, it prompts for a pop-up window for the user to enter the username and password.

Comment: Could you please try [Auth Bot](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-auth-node/blob/master/manifest/AuthBot.zip) manifest and check if you are getting the same issue?

Comment: When I click on 'Sign in' button from my mobile, it gives me a 403 Error: disallowed_useragent.
"Google can't sign you in safely inside this app. You can use Google sign-in by visiting this app's webite in a browser like Safari or Chrome"

Comment: Did Auth Bot manifest shared by us worked for you? Could you please share your App Manifest which we could try at our end? You could share it on email alias mentioned in [feedback page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback).

Comment: No @Wajeed-MSFT. What I meant in the previous comment is that I am getting the error mentioned with the Auth Bot manifest.

Comment: I have emailed the Manifest file to the teams dev email id

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Do we have an update on this yet, we would really like to use and offer this functionality to our clients.

Comment: Sorry for delay in response. I see that you are using SDK1.0, could you please try using [latest Teams Client SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/msteams-client?view=msteams-client-js-latest#using-the-sdk)? Also, could you please put alert and see what all values you are getting in  microsoftTeams.getContext()?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT I changed the SDK version to latest. And the microsoftTeams.getContext() returns [object object]. It contains the correct values for ChannelId, TeamId, EntityId, etc. from my index page, which I am using to set it to session. Once this is done, I redirect it to my custom page that loads my application. In that page I am not using any microsoftTeams object.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT I was wondering how the MS DevOps site is implemented. I could add it into Teams and when I click on the "go to website" button, it works perfectly with all the selections I made in the Teams getting loaded into the browser.
We are really stuck with this issue and any help to solve it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Some help in this area would be appreciated...

Comment: We have added page in documentation for [Tabs on mobile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/design/framework/tabs-mobile). Could you please take a look and see if that help?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT I mean MS Teams windows app, not the mobile app

Comment: [Go to website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wth3f.png) option takes user outside of Microsoft Teams context. You won't be able to fetch Teams context in the page opened inside browser. Solution would be to ask user to Sign in and use [Graph APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teams-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) to fetch details.

Comment: Thanks @Wajeed-MSFT, it is clear now.